# Rails layouts per action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use a different layout for some actions (mostly for the new action in most of the controllers).

I am wondering what the best way to specify the layout would be? (I am using 3 or more different layouts in the same controller)

I don't like using

> render :layout => 'name'

I liked doing

> layout 'name', :only => [:new]

But I can't use that to specify 2 or more different layouts.

For example:

When I call layout 2 times in the same controller, with different layout names and different only options, the first one gets ignored - those actions don't display in the layout I specified.

Note: I'm using Rails 2.

Comment: The Rails Guides documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

Comment: Good point. The documentation for Rails 2: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/layouts_and_rendering.html#finding-layouts

Comment: (Also, I posted the guide to help future readers. I have no doubt you had your problem solved a long time ago ;-)

Answer (score 318, accepted):

You can use a method to set the layout.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :resolve_layout

  # ...

  private

  def resolve_layout
    case action_name
    when "new", "create"
      "some_layout"
    when "index"
      "other_layout"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. And in case someone wants to do simpler things with one-liner the following is possible. Its easy to read and place in top of the controller.
---
`layout Proc.new{ ['index', 'new', 'create'].include?(action_name) ? 'some_layout' : 'other_layout' }`

Comment: Would this have a large effect on application performance if various layouts are using say several different css & js files respectively?

Comment: -1: Too complex. The comment below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21203783/285154) is the best option.

Comment: Thanks! This is still a problem in Rails 4.2, perhaps only if you are using inheriting controllers in many levels. I have used method before, but wasn't thinking of testing that when I had the problem now, thanks again.

Comment: @dimitko no it's not, I already referenced that solution in the question itself. It does not work if you want to use 3 or more different layouts (as is exactly my case).

Comment: @LucaGuidi how is this not thread safe? The method / proc has no side effects.

Comment: See also [Choosing Layouts at Runtime in this Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#choosing-layouts-at-runtime)

Comment: 6 years later I must tell you @dimitarvp, although both answers solve the question, they're meant to work in a different way.

Answer (score 222):

If you are only selecting between two layouts, you can use [`:only`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#conditional-layouts):

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   layout "admin", only: [:new, :edit]
end
```

or

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
   layout "application", only: [:index]
end
```

Comment: Well, the problem with this is that you cannot access objects such as current_user to conditionally determine the layout

Comment: @AndrewK Dynamically choosing a layout doesn't seem to be part of the question asked.

Comment: If any of you read the question you would know this is not the right answer, as I have already described this solution in the question itself and also why it does not work in my case (3 or more layouts).

Comment: Like mrbrdo said, this is not the answer. His question specifically indicates `(I am using 3 or more different layouts in the same controller)`. This answer allows a layout and no layout, *not* different layouts.

Answer (score 55):

You can specify the layout for an individual action using [respond_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#listing-all-posts):

```
  def foo
    @model = Bar.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render :layout => 'application'}
    end
  end
```

Comment: To me this is the more flexible answer.  DRYing things out by applying `layout "[...]" to the controller class only allows one statement effectively.  If you have more than two layouts to deal with (say, admin, generic_app, tailored_app), you will experience `Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action` errors; and you have no choice but to use this suggestion.

Comment: This answer is the best, its simple and neat as opposed to using methods with switch or if statements inside.

Comment: also it can specify the erb file and layout both:
`format.html { render 'custom_index', layout: 'application' }` 

in the same way.

Answer (score 17):

You can also specify the layout for action using render:

```
def foo
  render layout: "application"
end
```

Answer (score 8):

There's a gem (layout_by_action) for that :)

```
layout_by_action [:new, :create] => "some_layout", :index => "other_layout"
```

https://github.com/barelyknown/layout_by_action

Answer (score 8):

**Precision :**

A not really but working DRY way is what you see above, but with a precision : **the layout need to be after your variables for working** ("@some"). As :

```
def your_action
   @some = foo
   render layout: "your_layout"
end
```

And not :

```
def your_action
   render layout: "your_layout"
   @some = foo
   @foo = some
end
```

If you do a before_action... it's won't work also.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 7):

Various ways to specify layout under controller:

1. In following code, application_1 layout is called under index and show action of Users controller and application layout(default layout) is called for other actions.

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
     layout "application_1", only: [:index, :show]
   end
   ```
2. In following code, application_1 layout is called for all action of Users controller.

   ```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
      layout "application_1"
   end
   ```
3. In following code, application_1 layout is called for test action of Users controllers only and for all other action application layout(default) is called.

   ```
       class UsersController < ApplicationController
         def test
           render layout: "application_1"
         end
       end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like my example:

```
def show
...
render layout: "empty",template: "admin/orders/print" if params.key?('print')
end
```

I specified the layout and the template html.erb if params print present.