# Rails 3 render layout in action causes error with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Im using twitter bootstrap for design. I want to use a different template for a specific action

```
def view
  render :layout => 'single'
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
   respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @movie }
 end
end
```

As soon as i add in the render layout to the action I get this error message

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

 Extracted source (around line #2):

 1: <%- model_class = @movie.class -%>
 2: <h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>
 3: 
 4: <p>
 5:   <strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:title) %>:</strong><br>
```

If I take the render away the page will load just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're rendering too early. Try this:

```
 format.html { render :layout => 'single' }
```

Or for a more scalable method, see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025784/rails-layouts-per-action).

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `render` in the beginning of your `view` method. Call it in the end.

**upd:**
Oh.. In your case you should call it in `format.html { render ... }`. Sorry.