# Styling body elements in Rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am currently developing a simple blog application in Rails. I am using two different layouts,  one for my articles pages (application.html.erb) and another for my static pages (welcome.html.erb) such as home etc.

The welcome layout requires the following styling:

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

These particular properties mess up the other pages using the articles layout.

1.Is there a work around for this kind of situation where you need different styles for the same type of elements present in different layouts/pages?

2.What is the point of having controller specific stylesheets e.g, welcome.css.scss and article.css.scss, if they are all compile into one single application.css file?

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Rails assets pipeline.  I am using rails 4.1.1 and ruby 2.1.1p76

Thank you very much

Comment: Why can't you put a class on the body in the welcome layout that adds that styling?

Comment: Yes thanks I think that will do.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your layouts you would have a `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>` **which basically tell rails to load styles from application.css** and now if you look at your application.css you would have `*= require_tree .` **which loads all of your stylesheets present in app/assets/stylesheets** and hence your styles are applied for both layouts.

**Fix**

*Since you are using separate layouts so simplest solution **would be to use different classes or an id(since it'll be unique in page as `@MrYoshiji` pointed out)** in your layouts*

```
body#home{//styles for home layout}

body#welcome{//styles for welcome layout}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use a HTML `class` on the body when there can be only one `<body>` tag in the HTML page. A HTML `id` would be more appropriate here

Comment: @MrYoshiji class will also work but it'll just make sense to use an id since it'll be unique. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. [Rails layouts per action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025784/rails-layouts-per-action)
2. Because it's easier for you as a developer to know what those styles are referring to. You'd often do something like this:

**one.html.erb**

```
<div id="one">
  <!-- code -->
</div>
```

**one.css.scss**

```
#one {
  // styling
}
```

That way the styles in `one.css.scss` are only being applied to the right html pages.