# Rails layout not changing between actions

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, caching, layout

I'm programming a Rails application. I want to use an specific style in the whole HTML tag in the index page, but the rest of the pages should follow the application layout. So, in my controller I have:

```
    def index
        render layout: 'index_layout'
    end

    # All other actions follow this scheme
    def any_other_action
    end
```

The index layout has an specific piece of code that changes the styling:

```
    <!-- Index layout -->
    <html id="index_html">
    ...

    <!-- Application layout (goes normally) -->
    <html>
    ...
```

However, when I change from window to window through a `link_to` tag in Rails, the layout is not being refreshed and the view remains with the id assigned in the previous page, for example, if I go from index to any other page, the html tag has the id index_html, and vice versa. However, if I perform a full refresh (by pressing F5 key), the layout is rendered properly. I tested in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome, in order to check if this was a browser peculiar issue, but the results are the same.

My server produces this output when I request index page, after I navigate to any other page through `link_to` tag and then reload this new page:

```
    Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
     Rendering home/index.html.haml within layouts/index_layout
     Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/index_layout (9.9ms)
     Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (13.6ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 1254ms (Views: 1201.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


    # Navigation with link_to tag, the index_html id is still appearing

    Started GET "/community" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-09 11:45:58-0500
    Processing by HomeController#community as HTML
     Rendering home/community.html.haml within layouts/application
     Rendered home/_community_members_panel.html.haml (6.1ms)
     Rendered home/_community_companies_panel.html.haml (8.1ms)
     Rendered home/community.html.haml within layouts/application (41.5ms)
     Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (10.6ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 110ms (Views: 101.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


    # Full refresh of the page with F5 key, the index_html id doesn't appear, as it should.

    Started GET "/community" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-09 11:46:49 -0500
    Processing by HomeController#community as HTML
     Rendering home/community.html.haml within layouts/application
     Rendered home/_community_members_panel.html.haml (5.6ms)
     Rendered home/_community_companies_panel.html.haml (6.6ms)
     Rendered home/community.html.haml within layouts/application (19.4ms)
     Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.haml (8.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 74ms (Views: 72.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Can anyone give me some lights about what could be failing? My intuition is something about cache, but I can't find any answer that can help me. My Ruby version is 2.5.1 and my rails version is 5.1.6

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025806/5239030

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @iGian, but the problem isn't about rendering wrong layouts, the right layout is being rendered (as the output of the server says), but it is not redrawn, or reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post this expecting this will be helpful for anyone with the problem I presented

The issue was the `turbolinks` gem. It appears that when you create a link with this gem, it reloads only the body of the page. For this reason, the html tag wasn't changed when redirected through a link but it was when refreshed. All I had to do was to add in my link tags the next code:

```
<%= link_to about_us_path, data: {turbolinks: false} %>
```

And so, the layout is fully redrawn, applying the desired changes.

Thanks to all for their answers!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to get Ur customer layout is to create a layout with the name of the controller as folder name and index.html.erb to reflect Ur action.

Comment: It is not a different controller. It's just a particular action within the controller. And I've created two layouts, and (according to the server) they're being served correctly. However, when I navigate with `link_to` tags, the full layout is not being redrawn, but when I refresh the page, I guess it's fully redrawn and the behavior is the expected

Answer (score 0):

**1)**

```
before_action custom_layout, only: :index

def custom_layout
    render 'layouts/index_layout'
end
```

**2)**

```
layout :layout_by_resource

def layout_by_resource
   if true #just check as you want here. controller/path/actions etc...
     "index_layout"
   else
     "application"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, this is how I've fixed it:

```rb
<%= link_to about_us_path, data: {turbo: false} %>
```

Working with Rails 7.1